# how to refresh a window without refreshing the images of the window in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program I wrote in C# with a window that contain a groupBox with image.

I have a button that do some things (it doesn't matter what exactly) and it refresh the window in his loop (in button_click function) (with this.Refresh();).

Does there is a way that I can refresh the window without refreshing the groupBox?

*I have another problem, I cant minimize the window while the button_click function working. there is something I can do to solve it?

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application? WPF? SilverLight? Web?

Comment: this is a windows application (in C# in .NET 4.0)

Comment: Do you mean `System.Windows.Forms`?

Comment: Do you mean System.Windows.Forms? yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Invalidate()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) instead of `Refresh()`

```
this.Invalidate(false);//false to not redraw the controls in the form.
```

**Edit:** [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx)

> Calling the Invalidate method does not force a synchronous paint; to
>   force a synchronous paint, call the Update method after calling the
>   Invalidate method

so:

```
this.Invalidate(false);
this.Update();
```

Comment: thank you Jalal. this was helpful. I have another problem, I cant minimize the window while the button_click function working. there is something I can do to solve it?

Comment: @George: Ask a second stand alone question, then.  They're different issues and will have different solutions.

Comment: @George: better way is to run the code at your button in another thread so it will not block the UI.

Comment: please notice that I posted the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714602/cant-minimize-the-window-while-the-button-click-function-working. there is a solution that not involves threads?

Comment: @George: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423606/how-to-lock-the-application-gui-in-c-winform/6424742#6424742) answer.

Comment: @George: in the left corner near the answer, there is a correct sign. click on it so it will converted to green and that answer then will be come the correct answer to your question. also consider checking [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)