# can't minimize the window while the button_click function working

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a program I wrote in C# with a window.

I have a button that do some things (it doesn't matter what exactly) and it refresh the window in his loop (in button_click function) (with this.Invalidate(false); (I don't use this.Refresh because I have a groupBox that I don't want to refresh)).

I cant minimize the window while the button_click function working. there is something I can do to solve it?

**lets say I have this code:

```
    void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = int.Parse(somelabel_num.Text);
        int i;
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        file.ShowDialog();
        if (file.FileName == "")
            return;
        this.Refresh();
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(file.FileName);
        groupBox1.BackgroundImage = image;

        for (i = 0; i < int.Parse(somelabel_num.Text); i++)
        {
            this.Text = i;
            this.Invalidate(false);
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
        }
    }
```

so how to do this as a thread that gets the paremeters?

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, you should consider running button task in one of many ways you can in .NET (Thread, ThreadPool, Task etc).

However, if you are looking for a quick fix you can try one of these things:

1. Call Application.DoEvents() to allow UI to process window message pump.
   e.g.

   ```
   WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
   Application.DoEvents();
   ```
2. Call minimization asynchronously
   e.g.

   ```
   if (InvokeRequired)
       BeginInvoke(
           new Action(() => WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized)
       );
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to run the code at your button in another thread so it will not block the UI when you press the button.

**Edit:** Code sample from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423606/how-to-lock-the-application-gui-in-c-winform/6424742#6424742):

```
private readonly object _userActivityLocker = new object();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(delegate()
    {
    if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(_userActivityLocker))
    {
        //note that any sub clicks will be ignored while we are here
        try
        {
            //here execute your long running operation without blocking the UI
        }
        finally
        {
            System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(_userActivityLocker);
        }
    }
    }) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
}
```

**Edit:** You stated at comment that

> exception is occurs when the code reaches to an openFileDialog call).
>   I get this exeption: System.Threading.ThreadStateException

You need to invoke the `OpenFileDialog` code in the form main thread. so inside the try block:

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dialog.FileName);
        }
    }
}));
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556330/threading-cross-threading-in-c-net-how-do-i-change-combobox-data-from-another/6556401#6556401).

**Edit2:** After seeing your question code updated, I will advice you to use  [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: I tried that and it seems that it have some problem (is occurs when the code reaches to an openFileDialog call). I get this exeption: System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

Comment: @George: if you are calling or using UI controls, you should `Invoke` the UI methods or properties in the UI thread.. For more information check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556330/threading-cross-threading-in-c-net-how-do-i-change-combobox-data-from-another/6556401#6556401)

Comment: this is making problems. perhaps, passing variables to the thread will help. how do I do that?

Comment: maybe there is a simpler way that I can pass parameters to the thread? The openFileDialog is not the only problem - after putting this part in a "/**/", there art still problems concerning variables that dont belongs to this thread.

Comment: @George: I need a little more code to diagnose the problem. Also note that you need to invoke whenever you are accessing a UI components like `TextBox` or `Button` from another thread...

Comment: can you show me how to involve the backgroundWorker with my code?

Comment: @George: Read that article and other articles about `BackgroundWorker`, play with it a little bit and try to use it, I only show you the path, you are the one that should pass through it :)